The usage of comma on clarity and non-essential parts
Is it fine if in my writing I consider everything essential, the usage of comma being considered to be just for clarity, and all additional/non-restrictive things being placed between parantheses? For me, it is too confusing to think of the comma as a mark of both non-essential things and of clarity. I often prefer to use commas when I want to make a slight pause or for the purpose of clarification. Sometimes it isn't clear whether a phrase or clause is additional or not; there are always cases and cases. Just look at these examples: "Alex always wakes up at six a.m. when her neighbor’s dog barks." vs. "Alex always wakes up at six a.m., when her neighbor’s dog barks." 
In the first one, is implied that Alex is only waking up at six when the dog barks; but in the second one, the fact that the dog barks is just for background; it is an extra detail in the description of what happens at that time. When I follow this rule, I need everytime to make a pause to decide whether the part in question is essential or not; but if I consider that the comma is just for clarity, then it is simple, because my focus is just on the fluency and placement of ideas. Also, as argued by ChatGPT response, sometimes we can separate with one or more commas an important clause/phrase if in this way the sentence has more sense (or expresses our ideas better); it also applies to the elimination of the comma in a non-restrictive context.
This is a valid interpretation?

The typos in this question make it hard to understand. Are you asking whether people will still understand you if you use commas in a non-standard way?


In general, I find that it's actually clearer when we use only the commas that are required, rather than extra optional ones. 2) While commas matter, right now there are other things that do more to make your writing unclear. I would focus more on making sure your sentences are grammatical and that no words are left out before spending much time on commas.


Questions about writing style are more appropriate for [writing.se].

You mistake the absent comma for an option. Not true that "the fact that the dog barks is just for background." The non-comma version means: Alex always wakes up (at six a.m.) only when the dog barks."

"Is it fine  if in my writing I consider everything essential?" No, that is not going to be true, and one gets to to consider their every word essential. Besides, we all add details that help, even though they are not essential and could be left out. Like "Besides" and "and could be left out."

Can the dog tell time, like a rooster, or what else is going on at 6 a.m. every day? Commas can't fix everything.

It is not clear what is mean in this question by 'just for clarity'. The question contrasts the use of commas 'just for clarity' with using them to distinguish non-restrictive from restrictive clauses, but using them for the latter purpose is sometimes an important component of writing clearly. Also the first sentence of the question mentions the possibility of using parentheses instead of commas to mark off the non-restrictive remarks, but that possibility is then not developed in the rest of the question.

B Alex always wakes up at six a.m., when her neighbor’s dog barks.
is (almost) certainly not defining. But note that the 'afterthought' parenthetical is also non-defining, but would be given parenthetical offsetting:
B' Alex often wakes up at six a.m. – when her neighbor’s dog barks.
ie B'' Alex often wakes up at six a.m. – that is, on those days when her neighbor’s dog barks at that time.
But note that B' can also mean
B''' Alex often wakes up at six am (at which time her neighbor’s dog barks).
Intonation would disambiguate in speech.
...............
Though sentences like
A Alex always wakes up at six a.m., when her neighbor’s dog barks.
are usually said to be non-restrictive, I've seen them used restrictively (ie 'on those occasions when' here) in cases where the sense is disambiguated by context (which it wouldn't be, here).
I'd always advise one to play it safe and avoid any possible misinterpretation brought about by the occasional non-observance of the usual rule. So, here,
A2 Alex always wakes up at six a.m. if her neighbor’s dog barks at that time.
B2 Alex always wakes up at six a.m. at which time her neighbor’s dog barks.
